# Android Monospace doesn't behave as a fixed-pitch

Tags: android, canvas, android-typeface

As you can see in the screenshot below the two different strings with the same length not drawn with the same width on the canvas. I'm using a **monospaced** typeface, so isn't it promised to be drawn with the same width? Is that because of the kerning?

```
Typeface.create(Typeface.MONOSPACE,Typeface.NORMAL)
```

[image]

Comment: How do you draw this chars? Via text view?

Comment: As I said on the question, I drawn on the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known kerning issue with monosapce font on Android. It looks like this is a quite old topic.

**Some people have already faced this problem:**

[Android Monospace fonts aren't fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042721/android-monospace-fonts-arent-fixed-width) - 2013-06-11

[Are Android monospace fonts actually fixed size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971249/are-android-monospace-fonts-actually-fixed-size) - 2016-06-22

[Android monospace space ( ) width is different than character width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557853/android-monospace-space-nbsp-width-is-different-than-character-width) - 2017-03-02

The issue also occurred in mobile web environment:

[Font monospace Android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594367/font-monospace-android-2-3) - 2013-07-11

where problem explained with missing glyph:

https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/issues/617

**Solutions:**

Option 1.:

Looking for an alternative fixed-width font might be the easiest way. Some helpful links to find one:

- https://1stwebdesigner.com/free-monospaced-fonts/
- https://www.fontsquirrel.com/ https://www.dafont.com/
- https://www.urbanfonts.com/free-fonts.htm
- https://www.1001freefonts.com/

Option 2.:

You can override text drawing using Spans. This post may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452941/5823014

Option 3.:

You can modify the monospace font file to fix kerning. This online tool can be useful:
http://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/

Comment: Most editor apps with monospaces are not real monospace, inclunding courier font. . Exception is the app `Monospace` that uses a real monospace font.

Comment: Researching many fonts, I've discovered that `Lucida Sans Typewriter` in the `Microsoft Word` Mobilie is a real monospace font.