# How to display an HTML monospaced arrow in the Android browser?

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

How can I display monospaced text that includes an arrow that is the same width as the other characters?

In Android Chrome, the arrow is inexplicably wider, as shown in the screenshot below, regardless of the font. I'd expect the arrows to be the same width as the other characters. On the desktop, the arrow character behaves as expected.

The wide arrow is making my text alignment look ugly. I've tried different fonts and different arrows without success. I couldn't get CSS to force the arrow to 1em width. (I don't know if the problem is Android-specific or happens on other phones.)

[image: Screenshot on Android]

Code:

```
<pre style="font-family: monospace">
IIIIIIII
MMMMMMMM
→→→→→→→→
</pre>
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dchom9gs/)

Comment: Would this help? [Android Monospace doesn't behave as a fixed-pitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56714282/4873616)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not cause by Android-specific, it's about the font didn't provide the marks. (e.g. `↑↓←→`)

For example, you can see monospace fonts at [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace&preview.text=%E2%86%91%E2%86%93%E2%86%90%E2%86%92%E2%86%96%E2%86%97%E2%86%99%E2%86%98&preview.text_type=custom)
only `Nanum Gothic Coding` provide the marks ( `↑↓←→↖↗↙↘` )

[Google Fonts search results 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud1V0.png)

[Google Fonts search results 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwfzJ.png)

[Google Fonts search results 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obLsc.png)

[Google Fonts search results 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmkYH.png)